# playing video on Android and iOS with html5

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm trying to play video on both iOS and Android devices.  I have an html table, if you click on a row it opens up a player that you can start with the corresponding video.  iOS works great with the code below but Android gives weird behavior where it opens up the player and a weird giant play button out of position. Any ideas?

```
<div id="player"></div>
<table>
....
<tr >
<td onclick="DoNav('kft0labfoeiv3f4kdvvm40imu4/video_ec9658f0c1855e2e2ac09ae284f5e6990dbf445d_1338304978.mp4');"> Mycamera
</td>
</tr>
...
</table>

<script>
function DoNav(theUrl)
{

// only add the player if it doesn't yet exist
if($('#myfileplayer').length == 0) {
    var mydiv = $("#player");
    var myvideo = $("<video id='myfileplayer' src='"+ theUrl +
       "' width='280' height='200'  controls></video>");
    mydiv.append(myvideo);
} else {
   $('#myfileplayer').attr("src",theUrl); 
}

$("#myfileplayer").click(function(){
    $(this).play();
});

} 
</script>
```

I've read this post [Making html5 video work on android phones](http://www.broken-links.com/2010/07/08/making-html5-video-work-on-android-phones/). But I believe I've got that covered in my code above.  Anyone see what I can do to get this to work on Android?

Comment: What is the android device? Have you tried a different one? Androids are notorious for having ..varying functionality.

Comment: I've only tried one: Samsung Nexus S Android version 4.0.4. That is all I have. I tried using the Firefox user agent for other phones but I find the user agent doesn't work to show videos playing.  As my iPhone plays video fine but the user agent doesn't. Any suggestions on how to test in other ways would be appreciated.

Comment: given that post is almost 2 years old, any chance that just a normal html5 video works fine now?  I would imagine ice cream sandwich has fixed the html5 issues from that post.

Comment: Have you tried a basic version of the page with a hard-coded `video` element but no javascript? It might help narrow down the problem.

Comment: off topic: but a quicker way to do the conditional addition of the player, is `if(!$('#myfileplayer')[0])`